# sharepoint 2013 result source api

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

i am trying to create new result source with c# in a console application and get error each time,
i succeed updating exist result source but can't create new one
here is my code :

```
using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://XXXXXXX/sites/SearchAdministration"))
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(oSPsite);

            // Get the search service application proxy
            SearchServiceApplicationProxy searchProxy = context.GetDefaultProxy(typeof(SearchServiceApplicationProxy)) as SearchServiceApplicationProxy;

            // Get the search service application info object so we can find the Id of our Search Service App
            SearchServiceApplicationInfo ssai = searchProxy.GetSearchServiceApplicationInfo();

            // Get the application itself
            SearchServiceApplication application = Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchService.Service.SearchApplications.GetValue<SearchServiceApplication>(ssai.SearchServiceApplicationId);

            FederationManager fedManager = new FederationManager(application);
            SearchObjectOwner owner = new SearchObjectOwner(SearchObjectLevel.SPSite, oSPsite.RootWeb);
            Source currentResultSource = fedManager.CreateSource(owner);
            currentResultSource.Commit();                 
        }
```

the error is in the commit function - 
"The operation you are attempting violates an enforced dependency between objects,
 such as depending on an object that does not exist or deleting an object that other objects depend on."
i have noticed that after the creation of the result source, the currentResultSource.id is all zero's

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign to the result source at least one property. Your code works if I assign for example a Name and the Provider Id to the currentResultSource;

```
using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://hostsite.host/sites/SearchAdministration"))
        {
            SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(oSPsite);                
            // Get the search service application proxy
            SearchServiceApplicationProxy searchProxy = context.GetDefaultProxy(typeof(SearchServiceApplicationProxy)) as SearchServiceApplicationProxy;
            // Get the search service application info object so we can find the Id of our Search Service App
            SearchServiceApplicationInfo ssai = searchProxy.GetSearchServiceApplicationInfo();
            // Get the application itself
            SearchServiceApplication application = Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchService.Service.SearchApplications.GetValue<SearchServiceApplication>(ssai.SearchServiceApplicationId);
                //Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchService.Service.SearchApplications.GetValue<SearchServiceApplication>(ssai.SearchServiceApplicationId);

            Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Query.FederationManager fedManager = new Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Query.FederationManager(application);
            SearchObjectOwner owner = new SearchObjectOwner(SearchObjectLevel.SPSite, oSPsite.RootWeb);
            Source currentResultSource = fedManager.CreateSource(owner);
            currentResultSource.Name = "Test Result Source ";
            currentResultSource.ProviderId = fedManager.ListProviders()["Local SharePoint Provider"].Id;
            currentResultSource.Commit();
        }
```